# Unsupported operand type in Python

Tags: python

I wrote a very simple script to get the product quantity, cost and average of a purchase:

```
from __future__ import division

def print_purchase(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print """You bought %r products and paid %r,
             for an average of %d""" % (arg1, arg2, arg3)

quantity = raw_input("How many products did you buy?")
cost = raw_input("How much did you pay?")
average = quantity/cost

print_purchase(quantity, cost, average)
```

It works until it has to perform division. I tried 'modifying' the code in a few ways so it could perform these operations (importing division, etc.), but I still can't make it work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "purchase.py", line 9, in <module>
    average = quantity/cost
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: you should convert str type raw input to int type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should convert `string` type raw input to a numeric type (`float` or `int`);

```
from __future__ import division

def print_purchase(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print """You bought %r products and paid %r,
             for an average of %d""" % (arg1, arg2, arg3)
try:
    quantity = float(raw_input("How many products did you buy?"))
    cost = float(raw_input("How much did you pay?"))
except (TypeError, ValueError): 
    print ("Not numeric. Try Again.")      

print_purchase(quantity, cost, average) 
average = quantity/cost
```

Comment: Might want to throw in some data validation

Comment: why do you import future division?

Comment: Thank you for the fast solution.

Future division seems indeed to be unnecessary here

Answer (score 1):

The function `raw_input()` will return the entered value as a *string*, so you must convert it to a number (`int` or `float`):

```
quantity = int(raw_input("How many products did you buy?"))
cost = float(raw_input("How much did you pay?"))
```